# Create a bootable usb of mac os X

Tags: boot, usb, mac

I'm on Ubuntu and I have a Mac that I need to install Mac OS X El Capitan. The problem is that the mac is not working (that's way I need to install), so I will need to create one bootable usb stick of mac OS X El Capitan installation on Ubuntu.

Someone knows how I can do this? I already have the image from apple (InstallMacOSX.dmg)

Thanks

Comment: If you prefer a GUI way to do this, Balena Etcher should do the trick. https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Answer (score 0):

Run `lsblk` to get the usb drive's whereabouts. For example, here's mine:

```
pekka@BIG-IRON:~$ lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                    7:0    0  55,4M  1 loop  /snap/core18/1932
loop1                    7:1    0 118,4M  1 loop  /snap/chromium/1424
loop2                    7:2    0 162,9M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop3                    7:3    0  56,2M  1 loop  /snap/bitwarden/33
loop4                    7:4    0  31,1M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/10492
loop5                    7:5    0  64,8M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
sdb                      8:16   1  14,5G  0 disk  
├─sdb1                   8:17   1   2,1G  0 part  
├─sdb2                   8:18   1     4M  0 part  
└─sdb3                   8:19   1  12,4G  0 part  
nvme0n1                259:0    0 953,9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1            259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2            259:2    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3            259:3    0 952,7G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt    253:0    0 952,6G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgkubuntu-root   253:1    0 930,4G  0 lvm   /
    └─vgkubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0   976M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

From this, I can see that my usb is at **/dev/sdb**.

Then, run `dd if=imagefile.dmg of=/dev/sdb`. You'll probably be prompted for root password.

dd is very silent, so there won't be any response from the terminal for a while.

I haven't used dd for dmg files, but it [should work](https://superuser.com/questions/505821/making-a-bootable-osx-usb-from-dmg-on-linux).

Comment: I already try with dd but the dmg available is not the installation itself... on a Mac Will create a installation partition in memory to install! If i burn this image to the usb directly then this will be invalid because will have only a pkg file